# How to use html in a php email

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to display a table, which has been written as a html script, in an email that has been sent using a php script.
Here is the script

email.php

```
<?
//email content
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "SBD Number Duplicate Notification";
$headers = "From: php_test";

//email message
$fd = fopen("table.html", 'r') or die("Unable to open file!");
$msg= fread($fd, filesize("table.html"));
fclose($fd);

//send email
mail ($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)
?>
```

Currently, the email sends to the address perectly, but only sends the html code and not what I wnat diplayed. Is there a php command that could display the html correctly?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it seems to do the same thing that i am trying to fix